# Chopping Input in HTML POST

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am writing a website where I need an SQL query passed around to bring the user back to a page I had it working fine until I added to it

Its input is being chopped where here ....eventStatus =
(I know it needs to be post, running as get to debug)

(Row internal id is gotten from an SQL query)
(the SQL normally is also a variable passed in)

```
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 7.0.6
Server Windows 7 64 (Its a school project)
```

Am I doing something wrong with the hidden input?

```
<form action='' method='get'>   
            <textarea name ='comment' rows='4' cols = '50' value =''></textarea>
                <button type='createcomment' name='createcomment' value='createcomment'>
                    Comment
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'internal_id' value ={$row["internal_id"]}</>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'sql' value ='"SELECT * FROM `create_event` WHERE `eventStatus` = 'Happening' and 'approved' = 'Approved'"'</>
                </button>
        </form>
```

Post Code php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['createcomment'])){
    echo($_POST['sql']);    
}



    echo("  
                <form action='' method='post'>  
                    <textarea name ='comment' rows='4' cols = '50' value =''></textarea>
                        <button type='createcomment' name='createcomment' value='createcomment'>
                            Comment
                            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'sql' value ='SELECT * FROM `create_event` WHERE `eventStatus` = 'Happening' and 'approved' = 'Approved' '</>
                        </button>
                </form>
        "); 


 ?>
```

Comment: `GET` URL has a limitation of 256 characters. Doesn't surprise. Use `POST` and let's know if the issue persists.

Comment: Passing the whole SQL query to script via URL.. Is that a new form of SQL injection attack I wasn't aware of?

Comment: In practice its going to be via post

Comment: and the error is still happening

Comment: You are doing this completely wrong, don't pass the SQL as GET or POST. Just don't do this.

Comment: Hey, you're showing your database table to the world.

Comment: This is really bad, just change the value of input[name="sql"] to `DROP TABLE create_event` and be done with it .... J/k DISCLAIMER: don't do that.  You could do `SHOW TABLES` that is what I would do.  It's shocking really, someone could own your DB in about 10 seconds.

Comment: Probably chuck full of unencrpted passwords  and CC cards, where is this form ( website ) again?......

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by no longer passing sql, instead a set number for set commands